# Convert a React Native function to class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class, react-native

I wanna convert my App.js main function to a class

I got this sample from the Expo tab navigator app template. it actually works but I usually use classes as own standard:

```
async function loadResourcesAsync() {
    await Promise.all([
        Asset.loadAsync([
            require('./assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
            require('./assets/images/robot-prod.png'),
        ]),
        Font.loadAsync({
            ...Ionicons.font,
            'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
        }),
    ]);
}

function handleLoadingError(error) {
    console.warn(error);
}

function handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete) {
    setLoadingComplete(true);
}

export default function App(props) {
    const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = React.useState(false);

    if(!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
        return (
            <Root>
                <AppLoading startAsync={loadResourcesAsync} onError={handleLoadingError} onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}/>
            </Root>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <View>
                {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>}
                {Platform.OS === 'android' && <View/>}
                <Root>
                    <AppContainer ref={navigatorRef => NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)}/>
                </Root>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The question is how can I put the other functions to work with the 
class, basically want something like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if(!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
            return (
                <Root>
                    <AppLoading startAsync={this.loadResourcesAsync} onError={this.handleLoadingError} onFinish={this.handleFinishLoading}/>
                </Root>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <View>
                    {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>}
                    {Platform.OS === 'android' && <View style={styles.statusBarUnderlay}/>}
                    <Root>
                        <AppContainer ref={navigatorRef => NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)}/>
                    </Root>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your two example actually are same thing, almost identical. One is using component interface, the other one is using hook via functional interface. Regardless of what you do, they should work. But your index.js needs to refer to something like this, `ReactDOM.render(<App />, xxx)`. Make sure the `App` is the right `App`, ex. the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I got your question or not...but probably this is what you are looking for:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {

    var handleLoadingError = (error)  => {
       console.warn(error);
   }

    var  handleFinishLoading = (setLoadingComplete)  => {
       setLoadingComplete(true);
   }

    if(!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
        return (
            <Root>
                <AppLoading startAsync={this.loadResourcesAsync} onError={() => handleLoadingError()} onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading()}/>
            </Root>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <View>
                {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>}
                {Platform.OS === 'android' && <View style={styles.statusBarUnderlay}/>}
                <Root>
                    <AppContainer ref={navigatorRef => NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)}/>
                </Root>
            </View>
        );
    }
  }
}
```